# Slow Website Pages - SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a website which is considerably slow at loading pages.

I have been told to look at my mysqlslowqueries LOG in the TMP folder.

I can see many queries listed here on a daily basis. EG:

http://www.ticketyoda.co.uk/concerts/bon-jovi-tickets/bon-jovi-tickets-stadium-of-light-sunderland-2/3550

```
# Tue Feb 12 08:02:41 2013
# Query_time: 53.289597  Lock_time: 0.001163 Rows_sent: 3  Rows_examined: 73556368
use ticketyoda;
SET timestamp=1360681361;
SELECT e.merchant, e.price, e.url, m.merchant_logo, m.merchant_name, e.eventname,    m.merchant_rating
FROM wp_events e
INNER JOIN ########### 
ON #############
AND e.uploaddate = (SELECT MAX(uploaddate) FROM #########)
AND e.eventname ='### ####'
AND e.date = '######'
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Would definitely appreciate help from anyone, I have tried other plugins etc but this maybe to do with the DB.

Thanks

Comment: The database is reading 73556368 to find 3 records, obviously that is the problem, check your schema, you will probably need to index some fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've poked around the website, and it's almost unusably slow.

It also claims to be powered by something called "ticketreview" - is that a software package you bought? If so, take this to the vendor, because the installation script almost certainly either left a whole bunch of bogus data in your database (you have relatively small numbers of artists/cities, and 73 million records), or it forgot to install the indexes on the database, or something else went wrong that renders it unusable.

If this is not 3rd party software, you have to work out what the bottlenecks are. That's usually not all that fun on a production system, so maybe grab a back-up and work on a development environment for a while.

Then, make friends with [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). It will tell you where the query can be optimized - it sounds like there are some missing indexes.

Comment: I agree and think the problem is that there is no Indexing on the tables. The query is simply to take a list of prices for each post(event) but not sure about 73 Million records. The database contains 5,000 unique events and 10,000 prices so not sure about this.

Thanks for looking, I will try and have a go at the issues.

Just wondering how I find where 73 million records is?

Comment: run that same query through EXPLAIN - if you haven't got that much data, it may be a cartesian join somewhere - hard to tell because you've hashed out the join, and not posted a schema - but is the "m" table join right?

Comment: yes, the m is a join. I can send you the full query. The exact query run in PhPMyadmin doesn't take long to get the results.
    INNER JOIN wp_merchants m 
ON e.merchant = m.merchant_name

Comment: I have just added an index to the table. It seems to be loading faster. Hopefully it is.